# Distributed Interactive Simulation Java development

Tags: java, simulation

I'm using a tool called Redsim to monitor the DIS (Distributed Interactive Simulation) information that is being sent over a network, and am using a tool called LVC Game (developed by Calytrix technologies) to present that information on a web page. The two tools are completely separate (i.e. they both get the details about the DIS information on the network independently).

Both of these tools only provide the option to view ALL of the DIS information that is being sent over the network. Given that some of the simulations I am running over the network are very large, I am looking at developing a tool myself which will allow the user to manipulate what DIS information they are presented with.

Although I have heard of DIS in the past, I have never worked with it, so this is my first experience of using DIS.

Having had a bit of a search for information regarding DIS, and found that there is a DIS library available for Java, I am wondering if there are any tutorials available for Java development with DIS? Specifically, tutorials for how to capture/ monitor the DIS information that is being sent and received over a network? Any help or guidance on this would be much appreciated.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Take a look at [Open DIS](http://open-dis.sourceforge.net/Open-DIS.html): it has lots of docs and supports several languages (including Java).